# Javascript DOM update complete event

Tags: javascript, dom

As part of a three.js scene, I'm updating and displaying an overlay when a point is clicked. The problem is the DOM content I'm updating doesn't seem to be updated completely when I display it by setting it's display attribute to block. Is there an event that happens when the DOM has finished updating? Or is there anyway to know when the DOM is completely ready so I can show it using JS? (nb: jQuery is not an option)

Comment: DOM mutation is synchronous. If you're evaluating some code that changes the DOM, it *will be completely changed* as soon as the code has been evaluated. Maybe you're more interested in *rendering*?

Comment: Also, can you show the code that you run when "a point is clicked"?